# How to keep a file in the project and refer it internally?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am making a C++ application in .net. I wanted to keep a file in the project  with list of few items which are static.

I want to be able to refer it from within the application as well.

I wanted to know, what is the common approach of keeping such files in projects so that they are bundled when the application is installed and referred iin such a way that the path is same for release and debug mode.

I am very new to C++ on .net and .net in general.

Comment: Couldn't you include the file as a binary resource inside your executable and then extract it during runtime?

Comment: what if I want to be able to modify it's content ? i want to maintain a log sort of file as well apart from a file that contains config info  that should be outside the binary which user should be able to manually edit in a text editor.

Comment: Load the resource, copy the resource, modify copy.

Comment: You should update your tags to C++/CLI.